# How to use QGIS to create GeoTIFF contour map to import into Mapbox?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, mapbox, contour

The final product I'm trying to achieve is a Mapbox interactive map with a colored contour layer.

I have a CSV file that contains rows with "LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,VALUE" in a 0.01-degree grid. I want to create a contour map by interpolating the points and creating a raster map. From my research, I have determined that QGIS should be able to do this, but I'm not quite sure how.

I believe I need to output a GeoTIFF to then import into Mapbox. I found this potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715804/how-to-create-interactive-online-map-with-contour-filled-plot-layer, but I'm hoping to get more information on Steps 1 and 2 of that solution.

Comment: What precisely have you tried and where are you stuck on "Steps 1 and 2"?  I think you should focus on Step 1 first and include details of it within your question so that potential answerers do not have to follow the link.

Comment: Specifically are you trying to show contour lines on the map, or hill shades or a hypsometric tinted map, or some combination?